# Why do we say "the wrong ____"?

Tags: idioms, definite-articles

When we want to say that something is inappropriate or an incorrect selection from several options, we often say that it is "the wrong [whatever]". For example:

> Ten o'clock is the wrong time to have lunch.

> I put on the wrong shirt this morning.

But this is surely incorrect logically, because the use of the word "the" implies uniqueness where there is none.

Ten o'clock is not uniquely the wrong time to have lunch; nine o'clock would also be wrong. So it's not *the* wrong time to have lunch, merely *a* wrong time to have lunch. And if I have a shirt that's not a good selection, then I may have several; yet even if I had several, I would still say that I put on *the* wrong shirt and not the more logically defensible *a* wrong shirt.

So why do we talk about wrong selections this way, using the definite article? How long have we been doing it? Is it something that arose from the history of the English language, or did it come to us from a precursor to English?

Comment: We use *wrong* because it is the right word to express something that isn't right for oneself. It's not wrong for everybody, just for the person who is making the statement.

Comment: @Robusto, you are focusing on the wrong word (uniquely wrong in this case).

Comment: We use *the* in that case because the shirt or lunchtime or shoe is *uniquely* wrong in that particular case. Again, for the person making the statement.

Comment: You are mistaken.

Comment: And quite apart from your rudeness, you apparently don't understand point of view. The speaker supposes there is a unique right time or shirt or hedgehog for a purpose or occasion, and so wishes to emphasize what is, from that point of view, precisely the diametric opposite of what is intended.

Comment: *[There is **a** right time, and there is **a** wrong time.] This time is **the** wrong time.* The definite article is not ***always*** used prior to the indefinite article. That said, I wouldn't ask a question and then be so dismissive of answers you don't like …

Comment: Robusto thinks that I have been rude, and Jason thinks that I have been dismissive. I may have been both of those things, but I don't really think I'm under any obligation to further explain what I think is perfectly well-explained in the question text. Besides which, if I was dismissive of anything, I was dismissive of a response which entirely failed to understand the question, and thus could not hope to stand as an answer to it; not of an answer to the question, as Jason suggests. But this question is a duplicate of the one linked by Laurel, so there's not much point in this discussion.